# How to detect multiple Ibeacon device using the Minor and major values in android virtual App (using the AltBeacon library)

Tags: ibeacon

I'm using AltBeacon library to detect the iBeacon device thru the android virtual app, detecting the single device it's possible using the minor and major

Example:

```
 Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
.setId1("586b537a-b56f-5a01-b931-7f2dcaade66c").setId2("3027").setId3("0003").setManufacturer(0x4C)
.setTxPower(-59).build();
```

Same I need to find the multiple iBeacon devices without using the minor and major values. Help me to find the solution for this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code shown constructs a Beacon object appropriate for making and Android app **transmit** as a beacon.  That code won't work to detect a beacon, even with the exact identifiers shown.  Are you sure that is code you are using to detect beacons?  I think you must be using different code, or it isn't doing what you think it is doing right now.

Comment: 1.How to identify the connect virtual ibeacon.. with the device.                             2. Like five Virtual devices connect with one beacon device.. have to know .. which Virtual device is connected? @davidgyoung This is a concern we need to implement. please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796573/multiple-virtual-beacon-communication-to-multiple-transmitting-nodes-ble @davidgyoung Can you please help us to clear this one.

Answer (score 0):

To detect multiple beacons and read their identifiers use the Ranging sample code described here: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

```
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {
                Log.i(TAG, "I see a beacon with minor identifier: "+beacon.getID3());
            }
        }
```